# Apache + Bind Problems

Tags: apache-2.2, bind

I am using VirtualMin on Debian-50-lenny-64-LAMP (Debian Linux 5.0). I've upgraded some packages including "bind". Since the upgrade, both Apache and Bind stopped working.

Here's the errors I get:

> Blockquote
>
> Starting web server: apache2apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 78.46.92.11 for ServerName
>   (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
>   (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
>   no listening sockets available, shutting down
>   Unable to open logs
>    failed!

and

> Failed to start BIND : Unknown error

I am sure that some files were changed after the upgrade and this is a simple problems to solve, but unfortunately, it's the first time I am in this situation and I just couldn't find a solution. I've Googled about the errors but still couldn't make it work. Now I am sorry I did the update. I usually make updates to have the latest versions of the packages that are installed in the server. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using init.d script to restart apache ? /etc/init.d/apache2 restart ? Because there is a constant bug in that script. use apache2ctl instead of it. much more easy way.
Lenny's init.d script is unable to detect/kill zombie apache threads. 
apache2ctl is able to kill them. 
try this command to restart apache

```
apache2ctl restart
```

to understand apache's problem. try "-t" parameter with apache2ctl. send output here. Also you can follow instructions given by apache2ctl. google search will help you more than you expect if you paste output directly to google. 
& you need to change Webmin's way to control apache. 
logon to webmin. Servers > Apache Webserver > Module config >  type `/usr/sbin/apache2ctl` in **Path to the apachectl command**. then check **Use apachectl** in **Command to start apache**. 

About bind. i need more information. you can get themm all from logs in /var/log.
try this command. to get all errors on your server.

```
egrep -r '(error|fatal|panic|reject|Error):' /var/log
```

if you find something suspicious about bind. paste here.

```
egrep -r '(error|fatal|panic|reject|Error):' /var/log | grep named
```

Answer (score 0):

I asked the hosting company to make a complete reinstall of the Webmin on the server. Apache starts now, but Bind still doesn't. It's so annoying!

Here's the result of "egrep -r '(error|fatal|panic|reject|Error):' /var/log"

> /var/log/syslog:Jun 14 00:23:33 Debian-50-lenny-64-LAMP kernel: [   10.001921] Error: Driver 'pcspkr' is already registered, aborting...
>   /var/log/syslog:Jun 14 05:59:34 Debian-50-lenny-64-LAMP kernel: [   10.022366] Error: Driver 'pcspkr' is already registered, aborting...
>   /var/log/syslog:Jun 14 07:05:16 bitrepository kernel: [    9.625869] Error: Driver 'pcspkr' is already registered, aborting...
>   /var/log/auth.log:Jun 14 00:27:50 Debian-50-lenny-64-LAMP sshd[2578]: error: lastlog_get_entry: Error reading from /var/log/lastlog: Expecting 292, got 1
>   /var/log/kern.log:Jun 14 00:23:33 Debian-50-lenny-64-LAMP kernel: [   10.001921] Error: Driver 'pcspkr' is already registered, aborting...
>   /var/log/kern.log:Jun 14 05:59:34 Debian-50-lenny-64-LAMP kernel: [   10.022366] Error: Driver 'pcspkr' is already registered, aborting...
>   /var/log/kern.log:Jun 14 07:05:16 bitrepository kernel: [    9.625869] Error: Driver 'pcspkr' is already registered, aborting...
>   /var/log/dmesg.0:[   10.022366] Error: Driver 'pcspkr' is already registered, aborting...
>   /var/log/dmesg:[    9.625869] Error: Driver 'pcspkr' is already registered, aborting...